# Wordpress custom taxonomy hierarchy insert

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, for-loop, taxonomy

I am having some trouble getting this loop to work properly.

I want to insert Country, State, City, Community from google maps as heiarchy in a custom taxonomy of wordpress. All the variables get set but when it runs through the for loop it only populates and inserts the country or 1st array $loop[0].

I am using $pastID[$d] to save the last term_id to use it as the parent in the next term. If this is just bad let me know.

I have to use Globals as I am connecting with an existing plugin also.

```
    $custom_tax_name = "location";
    $loop = array();
    $loop[0] = $country = $GLOBALS['custom_array']['country'];
    $loop[1] = $state = $GLOBALS['custom_array']['state'];
    $loop[2] = $city = $GLOBALS['custom_array']['city'];
    $loop[3] = $community = $GLOBALS['custom_array']['community'];

$pastID = array();
$terms = array();

for($i = 0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $d = $i - 1;
    if (!empty($loop[$i])){
        $term_exist = term_exists( $loop[$i], $custom_tax_name );
        if (!$term_exist){
            if ($i == 0){
            $pastID[$d] = wp_insert_term("$loop[$i]", $custom_tax_name);   
            } else {
                if (empty($pastID[$d]['term_id'])){
                    $term = get_term_by('name', $loop[$i], $custom_tax_name);
                    $termParent = $term ? $term->parent : false;
                        if ($termParent == false){
                            continue;
                        }
                    $pastID[$d] = wp_insert_term("$loop[$i]", $custom_tax_name, array("parent" => $termParent));
                } else {
                    $termParent = $pastID[$d]['term_id'];
                    $pastID[$d] = wp_insert_term("$loop[$i]", $custom_tax_name, array("parent" => $termParent));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $pastID[$d] = $term_exist;
        }
        $terms[] = $loop[$i];
        delete_option('{$custom_tax_name}_children');
    } // nothing exist

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I was able to figure this out after taking a look and feel a little slow here.

the $pastID needed to have $i variable when setting it and $d when referencing it on the next loop. The code below will create a hierarchy taxonomy up to 4+ deep using my variables for country, state, city, and community. It will check if the variable exist and if it does not it will make sure it has a parent to associate it with or not insert it. Anyways thanks.

```
for($i = 0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $d = $i - 1;
    if (!empty($loop[$i])){
        $term_exist = term_exists( $loop[$i], $custom_tax_name );
        if (!$term_exist){
            if ($i == 0){
            $pastID[$i] = wp_insert_term($loop[$i], $custom_tax_name);   
            } else {
                if (empty($pastID[$d]['term_id'])){
                    $term = get_term_by('name', $loop[$i], $custom_tax_name);
                    $termParent = $term ? $term->parent : false;
                        if ($termParent == false){
                            continue;
                        }
                    $pastID[$i] = wp_insert_term($loop[$i], $custom_tax_name, array("parent" => $termParent));
                } else {
                    $termParent = $pastID[$d]['term_id'];
                    $pastID[$i] = wp_insert_term("$loop[$i]", $custom_tax_name, array("parent" => $termParent));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $pastID[$d] = $term_exist;
        }
        $terms[] = $loop[$i];
        delete_option('{$custom_tax_name}_children');
    } // nothing exist

}
```